# Trying to moving Jenkins Home directory

Tags: jenkins

I have moved Jenkins home directory in centos 7 and version of jenkins is 2.138-1.1.

These are the steps  I have followed:

```
sudo systemctl stop jenkins.
sudo cp -prvf /var/lib/jenkins /data.
```

Change JENKINS_HOME in /etc/sysconfig/jenkins

```
JENKINS_HOME=/data 

sudo usermod -d /data jenkins .
chown -R jenkins:jenkins /data .
sudo systemctl start jenkins .
```

When I run the build manually it throws the following error.

```
stderr: fatal: cannot exec '/data/workspace/test- 
job@tmp/pass7291433045594462450.sh': Permission denied .
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Probably the problem is in the job not in jenkins itself.

Comment: ensure that Jenkins has permission to access  the new location

Comment: Jenkins user is the owner and has read/write/execute permissions on the directory

Answer (score 0):

I still can't figure out Where exactly the problem was. I have tried set up on local machine, it worked well and also on cloud instance as well. The problem may be my attached EBS volume for jenkins home directory, I am able to build the jobs after this command.
sudo mount -o remount --rw /dev/xvdf /data